# Adding dynamically roles in the web.php - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I'm working with the Zizaco Entrust, and the platform I'm developping allows the user to create new roles, but when I declare which roles have access in the web.php I want to be dynamic.

**This is my web.php**

```
Auth::routes();
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Route::group(['middleware'=> 'revalidate'], function(){ 
$a = DB::table('roles')->where('acceso', true)->get();
foreach ($a as $item) {
    $array[] = $item->name;
}
list($keys,$values) = array_divide($array);
$newArray = array_except($values, ['superadmin']);
$b = implode('|', $newArray);

Route::group(['prefix' => 'ControlPanel', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'role:superadmin|' . $b], 'namespace' => 'controlpanel'], function () {

    // Dashboard
    Route::resource('/', 'DashboardController');

    // Donantes
    Route::resource('/donantes','DonanteController');

    // Tarjetas de creditos donantes
    Route::resource('/tarjetas','TarjetaController');

    // Paises
    Route::resource('/paises','PaisController');

    // Tipos de donantes
    Route::resource('/tipo-donantes','TipoDonanteController');

    // Montos de donaciones
    Route::resource('/monto-donaciones','MontoDonacionController');

    // Roles administrativos
    Route::resource('/roles-administrativos','RoleController');

    // Administrativo
    Route::resource('/administradores','UserController');

    // Administrativo
    Route::resource('/configuraciones','ConfigController');

    // Administrativo
    Route::resource('/monedas','MonedaController');

    // Transacciones
    Route::resource('/transacciones','TransaccionController');

    // Calendario
    Route::resource('/calendario','CalendarioController');

    // Calendario
    Route::resource('/campaigns','CampaignController');

    // User information
    Route::any('/user/{id}','QueryController@user');

    // Actualizar informacion dashboard
    Route::get('/update-data/ledger','UpdateDataController@ledger');

    // Processar tarjetas programadas
    Route::get('/processcards','UpdateDataController@processcards');

    // ipaccess
    Route::resource('/ipaccess','IpController');

    // Log files
    Route::resource('/logfiles','LogfileController');

});


});
```

But when I run the `php artisan migrate` I get this error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                    
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  no existe la relación «roles»                                               
LINE 1: select * from "roles" where "acceso" = $1                                                                                             
^ (SQL: select * from "roles" where "acceso" = 1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[PDOException]                                                                                                          
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  no existe la relación «roles»                                               
LINE 1: select * from "roles" where "acceso" = $1
```

First of all I don't understand why the `php artisan migrate` is pointing to the `web.php`.

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the Illuminate source code, you'll find `artisan` is a containerized version of your application for the console, or in other words and instance of `Container`. Therefore, it goes through much the same bootstrapping process as your application does when ran as the full stack. So naturally the database layer will be bind to the container. That is why you are seeing the error you are. How do you suppose the command `php artisan route:list` works? It must start the application, register the router and map the routes, meaning accessing your route files.

As for the error, have you migrated your database beforehand? I don't speak Spanish very well but that appears to be saying the roles table doesn't exist.  If you have migrated and are still seeing the error, specify the database connection for all your `DB::` calls like so:

```
$a = DB::connection('my_connection')->table('roles')->where('acceso', true)->get();
```

Comment: I get that error when I run the `php artisan migrate`.

Comment: So where you wrote `DB::connection('my_connection')` I should write the database name?

Comment: Yes, start with specifying the database name.

Comment: Got this error now: `[InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                              Database [sistemas_donaciones] not configured. `

Comment: Is the database `sistemas_donaciones` created and do you have a `config/database.php` entry for it?

Comment: Yes, I have it on my PgAdmin III, and this is my database.php: `'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],`

Comment: Don't know if this is giving troubles: `'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),` @btl